# Changing CPU architecture in build.prop won't effect browser

Tags: browser, android

Web pages using `NavigatorObject` can query my platform and see that it is armv7l. for testing reasons i need impersonate i686 CPU. when i edit `ro.product.cpu.abi` at system/build.prop it doesn't change anything. are there more files to edit?